# How to read the content from a (local) file with SpiderMonkey on the command line?

Tags: javascript, file-io, spidermonkey

I want to use SpiderMonkey for driving a test harness (for the in-browser version see [here](http://dig.csail.mit.edu/hg/tabulator/?mf=869d15233fe7;path=/chrome/content/test/;style=gitweb)). Now, I tried the following:

```
var defaultFileName = "all.n3";
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(defaultFileName);
reader.onload = fileLoaded;
```

which fails with the following error:

```
regression-tests.js:9: ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I did look around here and RTFMd for a bit but wasn't able to figure what to do (import? how?).

Answer (score 4):

Check out help() in the SpiderMonkey shell -- it tells you about a whole bunch of functions that are available in the shell-only version (like `snarf`, which is our (weirdly) named function to read a file into a string -- not sure the history of that name). It's a different API than is available in the browser, because the shell is supposed to be a minimal JS execution engine.

Answer (score 0):

FileReader is an XUL component. XUL components aren't available the standalone version of SpiderMonkey - they're provided by the browser.